# 12V regulator for 100W LED

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, constant-current, linear-regulator

I want to make a 100W high power LED headlight for bike, but the problem is that LED releases a lot of heat, and I'm using a 150W boost converter to convert 12V to 30V ( minimum operating voltage of 100W LED), to reduce the heat I have to reduce the current to 1A(from battery it is 6A), and for that I'm thinking to use l7812
which is a 12V linear voltage regulator but, it will not be able to handle that much amount of current I think so. Can I ue linear voltage regulator or sothing else?
I'm experienced with printing PCBs using toner transfer and also with soldering.
I'm confused what to do please suggest me a solution
LED specs- 100W 32-35V  3000mA  Genesis's 30Mil

Comment: Why do you want a boost converter *and* a linear regulator? Why 30V? Obviously you're aware that if you have 1A at 30V that's not 100W any more? What's the power supply for all this, batteries?

Comment: If I read your question as it is written now, you boost 12V to 30V and are asking how to solve turning that back into 12V with an LM78-series without the heat. I'd think not boosting the original 12V would accomplish that.

Comment: Boost converter because 100W led operates on 30V

Comment: Can we get LED specs? How did you get that the battery you will draw 6A? That is entirely dependant on the load.

Comment: When I connect the LED with boost converter in series with my multimeter then I get that reading

Comment: what is the battery capacity and nominal voltage?

Comment: its a 12V exide powerful battery which is used in bikes. when fully charged it gives open circuit voltage of 12.54V and 17A current

Comment: Genrally battery capacity will be in terms of Ah (Ampere hours)

Comment: It is not printed on the battery

Comment: Boost to about the voltage needed by the LED. Sense LED current and adjust voltage up or down so current meets desired value. This is a VERY standard method. Then there is no linear regulator needed. LED will still need heat sink. Heat sink energy is about 60% of Watts in. The rest leaves as light!

Comment: Russel McMahon, If I exeed the 30V then I'll reduce its life and if I got down even below to around 27V I can only get 50% of its total light output. However Boost converter is very efficient and will not drop more than 500mA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you measured your LED drawing 6 A from a 30 V supply (if I understand right), that was 180 W. Your LED would not last long at that power. You do need a way to limit the current.

Best would be to find a 100 W current-regulated boost LED driver instead of a voltage-regulated boost regulator. Then you don't need any other components.

If you want to use a linear regulator, get a low-dropout regulator configured as a current and not as a voltage regulator. Then set the boost voltage as close to the LED voltage as the regulator dropout voltage will allow. If it's only one or two volts and 1 A, then only a couple Watts will be dissipated in the linear regulator, which is OK with an appropriate heatsink.

A word of caution about mounting a 100 W LED on a bike (I assume you mean bicycle): you really want to make sure that you have appropriate optics and diffusers in front of that LED so that the light comes from a large surface area (like car headlights) and not from a very small, 1 cm\$^2\$ point source. Otherwise you will badly blind anyone coming towards you, maybe even damaging their retinas, possibly causing an accident which may also involve you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wonder can I use mosfet to do so? And it is the for the headlight of motorcycles, and I'm using collimator lens to focus the light and end the risk

Comment: For a MOSFET-based circuit you can have a look here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Circuits-for-using-High-Power-LED-s/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Thank you once again! Exactly found out what I was looking for